# Range for which the Verhulst-Pearl model is a good approximate

Tags: ecology, theoretical-biology, population-biology

The Verhulst-Pearl model describes the growth of a population using the differential equation,
$$\frac{dN}{dt}=rN \left(\frac{K-N}{K} \right)$$
where N is the population (no. of organisms), r, the intrinsic growth factor and K the carrying capacity of Nature for that species.
Solving the differential equation, we can obtain a relation between time and instantaneous population, given as,
$$\frac{N}{K-N}=\frac{N_o}{K-N_o}e^{\frac{rt}{K}}$$
Where $N_o$ is the initial population. 
[image]
For a general value of $N_o$, the logistic growth model can predict the the population fairly accurately. But I don't think the graph would be entirely correct if we have very low or very high values of initial population (nearing saturation).

So, What is the range of initial population where the logistic model works as a good approximate?

Comment: "I don't think the graph would be entirely correct if we have very low or very high values of initial population." Why?

Comment: @AdhishSethi For very low populations, I guess external factors play a much pronounced role, and fluctuations are fairly high. For the very high values (still less than K), I think the graph would exceed the carrying capacity and later come down to the value of K (not in the way the graph shows).